# How can I set the name of a sqlite3 database as a python variable?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to set the name of a sqlite3 database as an input from the user, but I can't seem to set the name of the database as a variable.

I tried to set the variable at the end of the SQL table creation, but that did not work.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any issue to do this. This is the simplest way you can use an users input as the name/path of the SQLite database:

```
import sqlite3
database_name = input("Enter the name of the database: ")
connection = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
```